# Android AlarmManager problems

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

I'm making and application in android using multiple alarms, and i want to do differents things for each alarm, my problem is that i don't know how to recover the id of the alarm or differentiate each alarm in alarm class.
This is my code:

```
//Activate the alarm
public void ActivateAlarm(int num) {

    int seconds =Preferences.getTime(num);

    myIntent[num] = new Intent(Settings.this,
            Alarm.class);

    pendingIntent[num] = PendingIntent.getService(Settings.this, num,
            myIntent[num], 0);

    alarmManager[num] = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
    alarmManager[num].setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            seconds * 1000, pendingIntent[num]);
    Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "Alarm"(num+1)+"activated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    .show();

}
```

class Alarm

```
public class Alarm extends Service implements Runnable {
public int alarmID;
private static Thread thread;;


@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    //  Toast.makeText(Alarm.this,  Alarm.thread.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //ReadFile.readFile(Integer.parseInt(thread.getName()));

        displayNotification();
    }
};

private void displayNotification() {
    //different notification for each alarm
}

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //super.onStart(intent, startId);
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start(); 


}
public void setIDAlarm(int pos){
    this.alarmID=pos;
}



 }
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can use intent.setAction("MyAction1")  and then filter your alarms with intent.getAction().equals("MyAction1") { do something ...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SInce it worked for you i'll post as answer for others:

You can use

```
    intent.setAction("MyAction1")
```

and then **filter your alarms** with

```
    intent.getAction().equals("MyAction1") { do something ...}
```